# Rotating looking glass icon in status bar

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've been wondering what the little symbol in the Visual Studio 2012 status bar that looks like this [image] is indicating. It is located in the status bar next to the current line number. It is animated and the looking glass is rotating.

So what does it indicate? And does the action it indicates, have an impact on the performance of Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?
I saw some Registry Tweeks for this , did anything help ?

Answer (score 0):

It's **the animation region of the Visual Studio status bar**, which displays a looping animation that indicates either a lengthy operation or an operation of indeterminate length (for example, building multiple projects in a solution).

It should not effect the performance of VS, just indicating the operation is undergoing instead.

Check out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is an indication of an operation running, I'm curious what operation it is.